# How to make this shake effect behave?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-animate

I have the following piece of code:

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function(intShakes, intDistance, intDuration) {
    this.each(function() {
        $(this).css("position","relative"); 
        for (var x=1; x<=intShakes; x++) {
        $(this).animate({left:(intDistance*-1)}, (((intDuration/intShakes)/4)))
         .animate({left:intDistance}, ((intDuration/intShakes)/2))
         .animate({left:0}, (((intDuration/intShakes)/4)));
        }
    });
return this;
};
```

The problem is that when I apply it, if the object is positioned absolutely in the center, it makes the object jump to the left of the page.

Can this be fixed? and how if it can?

Comment: Hungarian notation is ugly. Using full type names instead of abbreviations is worse.

Comment: It's not mine, the code, I found it here on stack, and I want to know if I can use it instead of jQuery's UI lib effect, I don't want to many libs included, I would like to use only jQuery without the UI and I found this piece of code which I thought would do the trick, so again, I don't code like that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using "margin-left" instead of "left" in your animate styles will have a better effect. You may need to play around with relative positioning etc. if it does not work first time

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `$(this).css("position","relative");`.  By setting `position: relative`, you are moving the element back into the document flow wherever it may belong, and then positioning it relative to that position.

In the case of absolutely positioned elements, you will need to keep them absolute and calculate the movement based on their current positions.